# Saving a dataframe after for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I run for loop on a dataframe. like below

```
for row in df["findings"]:
   GPT2_model = TransformerSummarizer(transformer_type="GPT2",transformer_model_key="gpt2-medium")
   full = ''.join(GPT2_model(row, min_length=60))
```

In this loop I extract one row at a time and then the `GPT2_model` model process and returns that row.
Now there are about 4000+ rows, I want to save these preprocessed rows in a datframe but don't know how?

Comment: Presumably the documentation and tutorials you searched for gave you some idea? What didn't work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using a for loop, cause the advantage of using pandas is exactly to avoid the for loops
in your place I would try :

```
GPT2_model = TransformerSummarizer(transformer_type="GPT2",transformer_model_key="gpt2-medium")
df["new_column"] = ''.join((df["findings"].apply(GPT2_model), min_length=60))
```